# Efficient code to load AVX vectors for 1D convolution kernel of length 8

Tags: performance, optimization, simd, convolution, avx

An implementation of a 1D convolution operation will often need to load a vectors of data that sequentially step through a buffer of data offset by one element each iteration.

For example, consider a buffer of input data *X[0]*, *X[1]*, ..., *X[n-1]*, where *n* is greater than twice the kernel length.  If the convolution length is three, and we can fit eight elements in each vector, we might first want a vector with *X[0]*, *X[1]*, ..., *X[7]*, then the next with *X[1]*, *X[2]*, ..., *X[8]* and the last with *X[2]*, *X[3]*, ..., *X[9]*.

Consider the case where the kernel length as well as the vector length is 8.  We must load eight vectors, that might look sequentially like this:

```
{  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  }
{  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  }
{  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  }
{  3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  }
{  4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  }
{  5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  }
{  6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  }
{  7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  }
```

By reducing this sequence vertically, we could produce a running mean or sum.  I.e., the sum of these vectors will have the sum of the first 8 elements in it's first position.

**Consider that the order of the elements in the column does not matter.**  Any permutation of the elements in each column will still produce the same result.  For a convolution, this permutation can be accounted for by altering the order of the constants used in the kernel.

Is there a faster way to load these vectors that takes advantage of this?  Consider as a baseline the simple sequence of unaligned loads:

```
// Any sort of sliding window function, i.e. running mean, running max, convolution, etc.
void sliding_window(const float* input, unsigned length)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length - 7; i += 8) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; i < 8; j++) {
            __m256 v = _mm256_loadu_ps(input[i + j]);
            // reduction operation on v (e.g. max or fmadd) goes here
        }
    }
    // handle tail here
}
```

Comment: Unaligned loads are fully efficient unless they split across a 64-byte cache-line boundary, so this is pretty good.  Maybe mix in a couple shuffles to balance back-end port pressure across 2/clock loads and 1/clock shuffles, especially in-lane shuffles like `vpermilps`, or others with immediate controls like `vperm2f128`.  But actual loads that are only used once can fold into memory operands for instructions like `vmaxps`, saving front-end bandwidth if the compiler avoids an indexed addressing-mode.

Comment: Good point about using the loads once and being able to fold them in.  I want to compute a polyphase FIR filter, so I'll use each load multiple times.  Enough that putting the data into a register will clearly be a win, but no much that that the loads and swizzles to produce the registers isn't significant.

Comment: I hoped to make the question more general by assuming that the optimum sequence of loads/swizzles would be useful for any sort of reduction.  But clearly being able to fold the load into the reduction itself makes a significant difference.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  If there isn't a front-end bottleneck, it only helps indirectly in terms of fewer ROB entries for the same work, allowing out-of-order exec to see farther.  (But with loads, shuffles, and probably stores, plus loop overhead, often there will be a front-end bottleneck, not back-end; even FMA has 2/clock throughput.  Unless cache/memory bandwidth is a bottleneck instead.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should note that if your convolution is separable, this is very often worth doing. Simple example:

```
res[i] = x[i]+x[i+1]+x[i+2]+x[i+3]+x[i+4]+x[i+5]+x[i+6]+x[i+7];
```

This can be done by convoluting with `[1 1] * [1 0 1] * [1 0 0 0 1]` in three steps, for example like so:

```
void sliding_window(float* output, const float* input, size_t length)
{
    // Nomenclature
    // aX input at i+X
    // bX convolution with [1 1] starting at i+X
    // cX convolution with [1 1] * [1 0 1] starting at i+X
    // dX convolution with [1 1] * [1 0 1] * [1 0 0 0 1] starting at i+X

    __m256 a0 = _mm256_load_ps(input), a8 = _mm256_load_ps(input + 8);
    __m256 b0 = _mm256_add_ps(a0, _mm256_loadu_ps(input+1)), b8 = _mm256_add_ps(a8, _mm256_loadu_ps(input+9));
    __m256 b4 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(b0, b8, 1+16*2);
    __m256 b2 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(b0, b4, 2+3*4+0*16+1*64);
    __m256 c0 = _mm256_add_ps(b0, b2);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length - 25; i += 8) {
        // Convolute input with [1 1]
        __m256 a16 = _mm256_load_ps( input + i + 16);
        __m256 a17 = _mm256_loadu_ps(input + i + 17);
        __m256 b16 = _mm256_add_ps(a16, a17);

        // Convolute first convolution with [1 0 1]
        __m256 b12 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(b8, b16, 1+16*2);
        __m256 b10 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(b8, b12, 2+3*4+0*16+1*64);
        __m256 c8 = _mm256_add_ps(b8, b10);

        // Convolute second convolution with [1 0 0 0 1]
        __m256 c4 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(c0, c8, 1+16*2);
        __m256 d0 = _mm256_add_ps(c0, c4);

        // Store result
        _mm256_store_ps(output + i, d0);

        // rename registers for next iteration:
        b8 = b16;
        c0 = c8;
    }
    // handle tail here ...
}
```

You can of course replace `addps` by `maxps`. Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/W9K9o943o

Overall, this takes 1 aligned + 1 unaligned load, 3 shuffles, 3 additions and 1 store for 8 elements (actually only using AVX1). On Intel CPUs with only 1 shuffle per cycle this may actually just be slightly faster than a naïve 8-load, 7-addition implementation (I did not benchmark this). On Zen3 I'm not sure about the actual cost of loading unaligned data.

If you have a non-trivial kernel it is probably hard to determine if it is separable, though.

Comment: I think I remember BeeOnRope mentioning that recent AMD CPUs like Zen3 have fully efficient unaligned loads when there's no cache-line split; 32-byte boundaries aren't relevant for them anymore.  But IDK about the actual cost of cache-line splits in terms of extra latency and possible replay of dependent uops like Intel has.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that in general, if the kernel is separated into N smaller kernels, then the total number of kernel factors increases by N-1.  I.e., 8 is split into 2+3+5 = 10.  So you only get ahead if the now separated kernels have more zeros in them. The `[1 0 0 0 1]` kernel is especially good because the lane crossing can use a permute2f128.  And if the kernels are normalized so the first element is 1 it saves one op per kernel (effectively mitigating the extra N-1 elements)  E.g., a*x[0] + b*x[1] is mul+fmadd, but 1*x[0] + b'*x[1], where b' = b/a, and it's just a single fmadd.

Comment: I should maybe emphasize that this just solves a (though quite common) special case. 7 consecutive `[1 x_i]` convolutions are probably not better than one `[1 a_1, ... a_7]` convolution. OTOH, for bigger kernels (maybe 16 or 32?) it could already be faster to do some FFT-based solution (search for "overlap-add method") -- the break-even point of course depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with is this sequence:

```
{  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  }
{  1   2   3   8   5   6   7  12  }
{  2   3   8   9   6   7  12  13  }
{  3   8   9  10   7  12  13  14  }
{  4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  }
{  5   6   7   4   9  10  11   8  }
{  6   7   4   5  10  11   8   9  }
{  7   4   5   6  11   8   9  10  }
```

Each column contains the necessary elements.  The first column contains 0 - 7, the next 1 - 8, then 2 - 9, etc.

This can be produced with the following sequence of operations:

```
void sliding_window(const float* input, unsigned length)
{
    __m256 a = _mm256_load_ps(input);   
    for (unsigned i = 8; i < length - 7; i += 8) {
        __m256 b = _mm256_load_ps(input + i);

        __m256i ai = _mm256_castps_si256(a);  // not part of sequence
        __m256i bi = _mm256_castps_si256(b);  // just for code reduction

        // a is the first vector, these are remaining 7
        __m256 j1 = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_alignr_epi8(bi, ai, 4));
        // Reduction operation (add, fmadd, max, etc.) between a and j1 goes here
        __m256 j2 = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_alignr_epi8(bi, ai, 8));
        // Reduction with j2 goes here, and so on after each value
        __m256 j3 = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_alignr_epi8(bi, ai, 12));
        __m256 r0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(a, b, 0x21);
        a = b;  // Register with "b" isn't needed anymore
        __m256 r1 = _mm256_permute_ps(r0, 0x39);
        __m256 r2 = _mm256_permute_ps(r0, 0x4e);
        __m256 r3 = _mm256_permute_ps(r0, 0x93);
        // Final reduction with r3 to produce result
    }
    // handle tail here
}
```

On Zen3, I benchmark this as about 10% faster than the sequence of unaligned loads.

Comment: How did you benchmark this? Without any operations on `jX`, `rX` they should get optimized away. Does the reduction step require load operations? Is your convolution kernel separable (e.g. `[1 1 1 1] = [1 1] * [1 0 1]`)?

Comment: Added fmadd between each to do a 1D convolution.  It might require a memory operand for the constants if one is doing a polyphase FIR filter, because there would be too many constants.  But one can do a number of sliding window type functions and the basic problem, producing a register sequence where the columns container the elements of each window position, is the same.  I suppose it could be considered part of the question if the reduction is fmadd, add, max, min, etc. makes a difference.